# Фильтр товаров в интернет магазине

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Ребят, в бд есть таблица с названием фильтров - `sorting` (поля: `id`, `title`), с пунктами фильтров - `options` (поля: `id`, `sorting_id` - `id` фильтра, `title`), таблица с товарами - `products` (поля: `id`, `title`, `price`), таблица с характеристиками товара - `parameters` (поля: `id`, `product_id`, `option_id` - `id` пункта в фильтре, `value`).

Помогите реализовать выборку товара по указанным фильтрам, сам написал запрос к бд, но работает некорректно:

```
SELECT `products`.`id`, `products`.`title`, `products`.`price`, count(*) as cnt 
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `parameters` 
ON `products`.`id` = `parameters`.`product_id` 
WHERE (`parameters`.`value` 
IN (3,8)) 
GROUP BY `products`.`id` 
HAVING cnt = 2 
ORDER BY `products`.`price`
```

`3` и `8` - `id` выбранных пунктов в фильтрах, они могут быть из одного фильтра или из разных `HAVING cnt = 2` указывает количество используемых фильтров.

Comment: У вас в примере попытка использовать parameters, а где упомянутые sorting и options?

Comment: Поместите group by...having в подзапрос и делайте join уже с результатами этого подзапроса как `JOIN (select...having...) AS x ON x.id=product.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поместить группировку параметров в подзапрос, то фильтр должен заработать.

`````sql
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, p.`price` 
FROM `products` AS p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `product_id`
  FROM `parameters`
  WHERE `value` IN (3,8)
  GROUP BY `product_id` 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
) AS x ON x.`product_id` = p.`id````
`````

Comment: Спасибо, единственное, ругался на GROUP BY products.id, заменил это на GROUP BY parameters.product_id и добавил count(*) as cnt в подзапрос select. Только проблема в том, что когда выбираешь в одном фильтре пункт, которому соответствует товар, товар вылезает, а когда выбираешь плюсом в том же фильтре ещё пункт, к которому не относится товар, товар пропадает, хотя, по идее, должен оставаться, ведь к первому выбранному пункту он относится

Comment: @Вячеслав Фёдоров Можете сделать песочницу на sqlfiddle с достаточным набором данных для демонстрации? Это бы очень помогло.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de1e04

Comment: @ВячеславФёдоров если я вас правильно понял, речь по прежнему о совпадениях в таблице parameters. Можно задаться целью искать по совпадению любого из перечисленных параметров, а можно искать только те товары, у которых присутствуют все перечисленные параметры. Совмещать и то и это не получится. В первом случае надо просто убрать всю фразу HAVING. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc38b5/2. Во втором случае, сколько у вас значений попало в условие IN(), такую цифру и надо подставить в HAVING. Например, если указали IN(1,2,4), значит HAVING COUNT(*) = 3. См. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4235b/1

Comment: спасибо, вот сейчас второй вариант работает, а не подскажите, по какой логике работают фильтры в других интернет магазинах, где при выборе вариантов в одном фильтре выпадают товары, относящиеся к ним, а при выборе пунктов в другом фильтре, поиск суживается. Вот это было бы идеально, но не понимаю, как реализовать

Comment: В общем случае сужение значит, что новое условие добавляется в запрос через "AND".
Тут, как всегда, надо искать баланс между простотой и универсальностью.
Советую поискать что-то вроде "фасетный поиск" или "faceted search mysql".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!